# Find word with maximum number of consonants and sum of consonants of this word

Tags: java

```
package lesson5;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class task1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence ;
        System.out.println(" Please enter senctence with space: ");
        sentence = sc.nextLine();
        String words [] = sentence.split(" ");
        String mostconstword = null;
        char [] constants = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f','g','j','h','q','x','z','l','m','p','s','r' , 'n', 't'};

        int maxconsant= 0;
        int totalconst = 0;

        for (String word : words){
            int conscem = 0;
            word=word.toLowerCase();

            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
                char wr= word.charAt(i);
                conscem++;
                if (conscem > maxconsant || word.indexOf(wr) >= 0){
                    totalconst++;
                    maxconsant = conscem;
                    mostconstword = word;

                }

            }
        }
             System.out.println( "most constant word = " + mostconstword + " sum of constants in this word =" + totalconst);
    }

}
```

Result I want to see:

I just could not calculate sum of consonants, the rest of all I have done. I need help just to calculate sum of consonants in the work with the most consonants.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please read [ask] and provide [mcve]

Comment: You seem to be missing any check if a letter is a consonant, and your list of consonants seems to be missing `kvwxy`.

Comment: provide some examples of what you want! E.g : abbababa = 4, aba = 1, abbab = 3! or something like that!

Comment: hi. when i will enter in console this sentence sample: "hi i am from Azerbaijan" i want to get result like that: most constants word = Azerbaijan and sum of constant in this word = 5.  is it clear for you ?

Comment: thi code help men find  mostconstant word, but i need help just to calculate summ of constants in this word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution, explanation is in comments

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class task1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sentence;
        System.out.println(" Please enter senctence with space: ");
        sentence = sc.nextLine();
        String words[] = sentence.split(" ");
        String mostconstword = null;
        char[] constants = {'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'j', 'h', 'q', 'x', 'z', 'l', 'm', 'p', 's', 'r', 'n', 't'};

        int maxconsonant = 0;        

        //Each word splited
        for (String word : words) {
            int consonantInWord = 0;
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            //Each char in the current word
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                char wr = word.charAt(i);
                //Verify if consonant
                for (char constant : constants) {
                    if(wr == constant){
                        consonantInWord++;
                        break;
                    }
                }                
            }
            //verify if maxconsonant
            if(maxconsonant < consonantInWord){
                mostconstword = word;
                maxconsonant = consonantInWord;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("most constant word = " + mostconstword + " sum of constants in this word =" + maxconsonant);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking consonants in the condition. That's why you are getting wrong count of consonants.

You can use `vowel` for checking instead of `consonant`. It will take less checking.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String sentence;
System.out.println(" Please enter senctence with space: ");
sentence = sc.nextLine();
String words[] = sentence.split(" ");

String maxConsonantWord = null;
int maxConsonant = 0;

for (String word : words) {
    int countOfConsonants = 0;
    word = word.toLowerCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char ch = word.charAt(i);                
        if(ch != 'a' && ch != 'e' && ch != 'i' && ch != 'o' && ch != 'u') // Not vowel, that means consonant
            countOfConsonants++;
    }

    if(countOfConsonants > maxConsonant) {
        maxConsonant = countOfConsonants;
        maxConsonantWord = word;
    }
}

System.out.println("Most consonant word = " + maxConsonantWord + "\nNumber of consonant in this word =" + maxConsonant);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are simply don't have **any** code to analyze the chars in your your words - as of now, you are increasing your "consonant" counter for each and any character in the word. In other words: you are missing the code that actually decides "this character is a consonant".

You got:

```
if (conscem > maxconsant || word.indexOf(wr) >= 0){
```

That doesn't help at all with figuring "is wr a consonant"!

And you defined yourself an array constants before - but you don't have any code there that would check if the characters in word are consonants!

One way to do that would be to go like this:

```
Set<Character> consonants = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('b', 'c', 'd', ...));
```

( the point here: a set is a much better data structure to check if a character is in it - if you would be using your array, you always have to iterate the whole array to figure if a character is in that array!)

... to use that within your inner loop:

```
char wr= word.charAt(i);
if (consonants.contains(wr)) {
   // its a consonant
} else {
   // it is something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If a correct mostconstant word is returned from you code then you can add the following snippet to count number of constants in that word

```
    int totalconstword = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mostconstword.length(); i++){
        if(Arrays.binarySearch(constants, mostconstword.charAt(i))>=0){
            totalconstword++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println( "most constant word = " + mostconstword + " sum of constants in this word =" + totalconstword);
```